# Not able to login to gmail by reading from the csv file , from the third mailid in the CSV file onwards

Tags: java, csv, selenium, gmail

I'm trying to read a CSV file containing Mail IDs and Passwords using java in Selenium .After reading it, I need to login to each of these mail ids in the same browser. I have given six usernames and passwords in my CSV file. While executing, its not executing from the third login onwards.

Error is shown like this:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='Email']"} Command duration or timeout: 17 milliseconds.
```

I'm using Firefox browser. Below is my entire :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {


        //csv reader aswathy -start
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/home/user/Documents/UrmilaDocs/CSV PAck/testCSV.csv"));
        String [] nextLine;

         WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
         String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
         driver.get(appUrl);
         driver.manage().window().maximize();   
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext())!= null){

        String user_name = nextLine[0];
        String pass_word = nextLine[1];

        System.out.println("Username: " + user_name);
        System.out.println("Password: " + pass_word);


//  //stackoverflow     
//      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();  
//       String appUrl = "https://accounts.google.com";
//       driver.get(appUrl);
//       driver.manage().window().maximize();   


        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Email']"));
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(user_name);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='next']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
             //try
             try{
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']"));
              password.clear();
              password.sendKeys( pass_word);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='signIn']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(8000);

        //click on 'Google Apps' icon 
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        //Click on 'Gmail' icon to navigate to inbox page
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb23']/span[1]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Login Success");


        //Click on user name first letter circle icon
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //click on 'Signout' button
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gb_71']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println("Logout Success");

        /*click on 'Signin with a different account ' option (since, after signing out from
//      the first user, he page is navigated to password entry page, which is supposed to navigate to 
//      username/mailid entry page  */
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-link']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
//      /* In 'Choose an Account page', Click on 'Add Account' button */
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='account-chooser-add-account']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
//          
    }catch(Exception e)
             {
                 System.out.println("Login failed!");  
             }// catch closed
//           //closing driver & firefox
             //driver.close();
             //System.exit(0);
            //end
        }   //while end

//      //closing driver & firefox
        // driver.close();
//     //csv reader aswathy -end
        System.exit(0);       //closing firefox  

  }   
  }
```

Comment: Have you logged out properly?

Comment: @  Sagar007: yes I had. I think, the issue is when trying to login with invalid username or password , its not navigated to username field entry page. What should be done for this?

Comment: Every website need some time to load pages. Most of website store cache  files. But in driver that cache file are not saved already. so that you need to wait for bit longer for get full page access. Because of that xpath also get element properly. Answer is already given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the problem is that, after 2 or 3 logins the page is not loading properly, thats why, its showing time-out and the xpath is also not getting detected. so, try to use **waitForPageToLoad** when trying to access gmail.

Comment: I have solved the issue. The problem was with xpath. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For fetching data excel file:

put excel data in ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> AL=new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void fn_FetchExcelData(int row_num) throws IOException{
               String WbookPath=TestDataPath;
               String SheetName=TestDataSheetName; 
               File FileObj=new File(WbookPath);
                  FileInputStream FIS=new FileInputStream(FileObj);
                  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                Workbook WBookObj=new XSSFWorkbook(FIS);
                  Sheet SheetObj=WBookObj.getSheet(SheetName);
                  Row FstRowObj=SheetObj.getRow(0);
                  int cellCount=FstRowObj.getLastCellNum();
                  Row RowObj=SheetObj.getRow(row_num);
                  for(int i=0;i<=cellCount-1;i++){
            Cell fstcellObj=FstRowObj.getCell(i,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                      String ColumnName=fstcellObj.getStringCellValue();
               Cell reqCellObj=RowObj.getCell(i, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                      String reqRowCellValue=null;
                      if(reqCellObj.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING){
                       reqRowCellValue=reqCellObj.getStringCellValue();
                   }else if(reqCellObj.getCellType()==Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC){
                       Double dblColumnName=reqCellObj.getNumericCellValue();
                      Integer intColumnName =dblColumnName.intValue();
                      reqRowCellValue=intColumnName.toString(intColumnName);
                   }

                      if(ColumnName.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")==false && ColumnName!=null){
                      AL.put(ColumnName,reqRowCellValue); 
                      }

                  }
              }
```

Get data from ArrayList:

```
int i;
        int loginid=AL.size();
        for(i=0;i<loginid;i++){
        System.out.println(AL.get(i));
            DriverObj.findElement(By.id("Username ID")).clear();
    DriverObj.findElement((By.id("Username ID"))).sendKeys(AL.get(i));
        DriverObj.findElement(By.id("password")).clear();
        DriverObj.findElement((By.id("password"))).sendKeys("123456");
    DriverObj.findElement(By.name("Button")).click();
```